# Is there a way to check DNS suffix of a computer in Unreal?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So I am looking to grab the Primary DNS suffix of the PC running my app. Is that possible in Unreal and if so how can I do that?

Comment: Computers do not have DNS suffixes.

Comment: Yes they can. "The DNS suffix of a computer is the part of the computer’s DNS name that follows the host name element. If you have a computer named mypc.accounting.contoso.com, the host name is mypc and the DNS suffix is accounting.contoso.com."

Comment: Computers do not have DNS names.